# Does log4j2 warn if no configuration file is found?

Tags: java, tomcat7, log4j2

I have no log4j2 configuration files defined in my classpath. My log messages are still going to the console and I see no warning about a missing configuration.

I am running a servlet based application on Tomcat 7.

I'm trying to figure out how it is getting this configuration?

**I am expecting to see the warning in log4j2 like you would see in log4j.**

Comment: Have you tried looking at the log4j2 code?

Comment: I did and found no references to the warning or reuse of the original class that had this warning. Looks like during the refactor/rewrite they got rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2 can autoconfigure itself if you do not provide a config file.

Configuration of Log4j 2 can be accomplished in 1 of 4 ways:

1. Through a configuration file written in XML or JSON.
2. Programmatically, by creating a ConfigurationFactory and Configuration implementation.
3. Programmatically, by calling the APIs exposed in the Configuration interface to add components to the default configuration.
4. Programmatically, by calling methods on the internal Logger class.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration

Comment: Yes I understand, I know it is capable of logging with a default configuration, log4j warned when it was using the default configuration. I was expecting to see the same message on startup however I do not. The message was something like log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (dao.hsqlmanager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Tomcat. When I removed the log4j2.xml file This is the message that I see when the web server starts:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Since the severity is ERROR, the message is indeed quite visibile.